# Is there a established color convention for US Federal Agencies?

Tags: cartography, symbology, united-states, government

Do US Federal Agencies have a convention for coloring the lands under the jurisdiction of each? For example, BLM lands are often yellow, USFS light green, NPS blue or dark green, etc. I've found [this](http://www.blm.gov/noc/st/en/business/mapstandards/colormod.html), but it seems to be for the internal use of a single agency, where I'm looking for public applications.

Comment: I'm not aware of any such universal agency standard. The cartographic standards are typically by agency and in some case by map/map type. For example I've never seen NPS as blue. Sometimes USFS and NPS lands aren't even distinguished - in fact many of the categories in your link are often just merged together. In cases where they are, I usually see NPS as a darker green - theoretically because they're smaller, so a darker color in a smaller area uses less ink and isn't as visually overwhelming as light colors in a darker field.